# Sencha Touch removing inline styles?

Tags: extjs, touch

I am loading a mask to cover my container which is working fine, however I noticed there is inline styles applied with `!important` so I have no way to override..

How can I remove this?

I am setting my mask using:

`container.setMasked({xtype:'loadmask',id:'myMask',message:''});`

and the output when I view the element in browser is:

```
<div class="x-mask x-loading-mask x-sized x-floating x-paint-monitored x-size-monitored" id="myMask" style="top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; right: 0px !important; bottom: 0px !important; z-index: 10 !important;"></div>
```

UPDATE:

So after playing around I managed to figure out how to change the inline styles. It seems the  element has setter methods so I was able to run `Ext.getCmp('myMask').setZIndex(20);`

Comment: Why you want to remove and What you want to add?

Comment: remove `z-index: 10` and set it to `z-index: 20`

Comment: Check the cls config for the loadmask

Answer (score 1):

You can remove default classes from mask using cls configs like maskCls.

```
xtype:'loadmask',
id:'myMask',
msg    : 'Please wait...',
maskCls: 'myMask', //maskCls will replace default class x-mask
cls: 'myMaskCls', //cls will replace default class x-mask-msg
```